# use Router navigate to go to newly created product in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I am trying to navigate to a newly created product after i click submit button. Now so far everything works fine but in my .ts file i want to redirect to lets say edit component of that product after it been created. How can i get the id of newly created component?
So far in my ts i have this which redirect to dashboard as soon as product is created, but i want to redirect it to edit that product

```
const newProduct = { ...product, price: +product.price };
      this.adminService.createProduct(newProduct).subscribe((response: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/']);
        this.toastr.success('Product Created Successfully');
      });
```

Comment: How does your `response` object look like? Can you `console.log` it?

Answer (score 0):

The `createProduct` method of `adminService` should return the ID of the new product, or more precise, it should return an observable that emits that new product ID.  What does createProduct exactly do ?

Your code will work with this mock implementation of createProduct:

```
  createProduct(newProduct): Observable<number> {
    return of(123456);
  }
```

Your subscription handler will get value 123456 assigned to `response` enabling you to navigate accordingly.